# Can someone explain me this sentence find in the internet like it is a common fact...?

Tags: sorting

I find this sentence in French, so I hope my translation is correct..
If someone can explain me, it will be nice :D

> To perform a sort, they do not implement in general a structure
>   converter to a real but rather a comparison function between 2
>   structures.

Thank you in advance

There is no tag "translation-resquest" here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they're trying to say is that if you want to sort something, you need a rule that tells you which of two things comes first.

Comment: Like you said it, its as easy as pie ! Thank you very much ! :)